# Simulating key hold without stopping loop

Tags: python, python-multithreading, pynput

I'm using pynput to simulate key press.

Here's my function i'm using in a loop

```
def press_hotkey(key, time):
    keyboard.press(key)
    sleep(time) #hold time
    keyboard.release(key)
```

Sometimes I need to press one key for certain amount of time, for example 2 seconds, but I don't want to stop my loop, as it should continue and press next key if needed.

What would be the most correct way to do that? Is running a function in new thread every iteration a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use threading module

```
import threading
```

and then call your function within the thread like this

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=press_hotkey, args=(desired_key, desired_time))
thread.start()
```